# Polling ignores commits in certain paths in multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-github-plugin

I have a multibranch pipeline with a project that I want to build only if there are changes in a specific directory.

I know that the `Polling ignores commits in certain paths` option can do exactly that but I can't find this option in the multibranch configuration.

Is this even possible for multibranch pipeline?

Comment: hi, did u find solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you can call the `GitSCM` class with an `includedRegions` path restriction in the `checkout` step (e.g. see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/66jF2uo8lSg) for the syntax).

However, this is not working with pipelines, as I just checked it last week. So unfortunately, Jenkins is really not well-suited for monorepos.